A problem about the fixed field of a Galois extension
Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of fields and $B\supseteq A$ are both Dedekind rings whose fraction fields are $L, K$ respectively. Given $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal in $A$, define $T_{\mathfrak{p}}=\{P\in Spec(B):P\cap A=\mathfrak{p}\}$. Then fix $P\in T_{\mathfrak{p}},$ the decomposition group of $P$ is $G_P=\{\sigma\in G:\sigma P=P\}$. The fixed field of $G_P$ is $L_P=\{v\in L|\sigma(v)=v:\forall \sigma\in G_P\}$. We know that $L/L_P$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $G_P$.
CLAIM: For any $\sigma\in G_P$, I understand that $\sigma(P)=P$, but why $\sigma (B)=B$? I know the fact that this is true, but I don't know why as $B$ is not contained in $L_P$.

Why is it important that $B$ is not contained in $L_P$? $\sigma$ acts on $L$

@leoli1 Because $\sigma$ only fixes $L_P$.
